# Hibernate Updating a one-one unidirectional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

Hi I'm currently spending a lot of time figuring out why my one-one hibernate mapping is not updating can you guys help me.

by the way I'm new in hibernate

This is the **BookingModel.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking")
public class BookingModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
String id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="teacher", nullable=false)
@JsonManagedReference
TeacherModel teacher;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="bookingModel", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
ClassModel classModel;

@Column(name="start")
Date start;

@Column(name="end")
Date end;

@Column(name="title")
String title;


//getters and setters
}
```

and this is the **ClassModel.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="class")
public class ClassModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private String id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="student")
private StudentModel student;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
BookingModel bookingModel;

//getters and setters
}
```

and this the method I'm trying to achieve

```
    BookingModel booking = find(scheduleId);
    ClassModel classModel = classDao.getClass(classId);
    classModel.setBookingModel(booking);
    booking.setClassModel(classModel);
    booking.setTitle("TEST");
    update(booking);
```

the setTitle is working but the class field in my db is still null

this is the **update method**

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void bookClass(String classId, String scheduleId) {
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user =          (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    BookingModel booking = find(scheduleId);
    ClassModel classModel = classDao.getClass(classId);
    classModel.setBookingModel(booking);
    booking.setClassModel(classModel);
    booking.setTitle("TEST");
    update(booking);
}


@Override
public void update(E entity) {
    try{
        Transaction t = currentSession().beginTransaction();
         currentSession().update(entity);
         t.commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: post complete update method

Comment: hi @VikramSingh

Comment: have you tried my answer ??

Comment: hi @mibrahim.iti, In my code im only inserting a the ClassModel to BookingModel

Comment: @RyanDelaCruz but you only update BookingModel and not update ClassModel (the owner of the relation) and i think this is your problem, can you please add this update(classModel); to your code under update(booking); and tell me what happen ? so you will update both entities not just one, just tell me what happen in this case, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because of BookingModel entity is not the owner of relation.

if you tried

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
ClassModel classModel;
```

**instead of**

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="bookingModel", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
ClassModel classModel;
```

with

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="classModel")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
BookingModel bookingModel;
```

**instead of**

```
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
BookingModel bookingModel;
```

so it should work in this case

OR you can do this too, and it should work without changing in entities

```
BookingModel booking = find(scheduleId);
ClassModel classModel = classDao.getClass(classId);
booking.setTitle("TEST");
update(booking);
classModel.setBokingModel(booking);
update(classModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as I think, is `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`. This annotation means that `BookingModel` and `ClassModel` should have the same primary key.

For example, this should work (there is not an `update()` statement):

```
BookingModel booking = new BookingModel();
booking.setId("booking");
save(booking);

ClassModel classModel = new ClassModel();
classModel.setId("booking");
save(classModel);

BookingModel savedBooking = get(booking.getId());
savedBooking.getClassModel();// we will have a classModel here
```

You are using `@GeneratedValue` with `id` type as `String`. Don't know for which database this is valid. Usually integral types are used with `@GeneratedValue`, for example `Long`.

There is not `rolback()` in your `update()` method.